# Makefile for sql parser... writing dependencies

Tags: c, yacc, lex, symbol-table

I'm implementing a sql parser in lex and yacc,
in that I use a symbol table which I kept in a separate .h file (sql.h) and in this header file I have some functions declarations.
The definitions of these functions are kept in a .c file (sql.c). Now I have included sql.h in sql.c,
I refer to the symbols and functions from sql.h in both my lex file(1.l) and yacc file(1.y).

The problem is that I'm not able to write a proper makefile for this.
I'm getting errors like multiple declarations.
Where do I include which file and how to write dependencies?
Please help. I have searched for a solution but I'm not getting it.....

#### Update:

I compile the code like this:

```
lex 1.l
yacc -d 1.y
gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c sql.c -ll -ly
```

I get the following errors after the third command of gcc:

```
In file included from 1.l:5:
sql.h:17: warning: ‘SQL’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
sql.h:18: warning: ‘SQL_SEL’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
1.l: In function ‘makeTable’:
1.l:80: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
In file included from 1.y:7:
sql.h:17: warning: ‘SQL’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
sql.h:18: warning: ‘SQL_SEL’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
sql.c:3: error: redefinition of ‘SQL’
sql.h:15: note: previous definition of ‘SQL’ was here
sql.c:4: error: redefinition of ‘SQL_SEL’
sql.h:16: note: previous definition of ‘SQL_SEL’ was here
```

sql.h:

```
#ifndef SQL_H
#define SQL_H
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct sym_table {
    char *token;
    char *value;
    struct sym_table *next;
};

struct sym_select {
    char **cols;        
};

extern struct sym_table *SQL = NULL;
extern struct sym_select *SQL_SEL = NULL;


void addSymbol(char *, char *);
void print(struct sym_table *);
void showTable(struct sym_table *);
void makeTable(struct sym_table *, int);
```

sql.c:

```
#include "sql.h"

struct sym_table *SQL = NULL;
struct sym_select *SQL_SEL = NULL;
```

And the definitions of the functions declared in sql.h

1.l file:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"
    #include "sql.h"
    int lineno=1;
    void makeTable(struct sym_table *, int);    
%}
```

.....  and othr lex file

1.y

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    extern int lineno;
    extern void yyerror(char *);
    #include "sql.h"
%}
```

.... and other yacc file data

---

Can you suggest me some other way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post your Makefile. As far as i understand there's also a problem with code, not only with Makefile. Or it could be that you try to make `1.o` from `1.l` and different `1.o` from `1.y`.

Normally the dependencies should look something like:

```
1l.o: 1.l sql.h; # lex invocation
1y.o: 1.y sql.h; # bison invocation
sql.o: sql.c sql.h; # cc invocation
prog: 1l.o 1y.o sql.o; # ld invocation
```

Probably you will also need to depend on tokens' declaration file.

EDIT:
Ah, so probably you need to put the definition of that table into one file, and the declaration into the header. You must first understand the difference between declaration and definition in **C**. For example if you have the following files:

**aaa.h**
int arr[]={1};

**aaa.c**
#include "aaa.h"

**bbb.c**
#include "aaa.h"

And then you try to `cc -o aaa aaa.c bbb.c`, you get the multiple definition error. That means, that the actual array must be in one file, and in the header it should be something like `extern int arr[];`

#### Update:

You should remove setting to NULL in sql.h. It's only a declaration there, that there is such and such variable somewhere. The actual value is to be assigned in sql.c.

Comment: actually code is working its just the problem of linking these files together...
i got to kno dat d problem is dat m inlcuding sql.h in sql.c and in both 1.l(lex file) and 1.y(yacc file).. dts y the symbol table n its objects are getting declared multiple times once in sql.c den 1.l den in 1.y... 
m nt able to get where shud i inlcude wich file and den how wud d makefile be.. 
the makefile u suggested is wat i had writn bt d error is of multiple defintion of symbols defined in sql.h....

Comment: and yes... 1l.o depends on y.tab.c d tokens declaration file.. can u pls let me kno how do i link all these file together.. i'm totally stuck at this.. Thanks.. )

Comment: i have postd my src files.. pls hv a look

Answer (score 0):

```
extern struct sym_table *SQL = NULL;
extern struct sym_select *SQL_SEL = NULL;
```

Remove the initialization `= NULL` from the header file.

Comment: yeah... got it right.. removed d NULL and it worked.. thanks.. ))))